# Jquery - Add same event for multiple table

Tags: jquery

I have a scenario that I have to bind same event for multiple tables.

Event on **table**:

```
 $('#table id').on("dblclick", 'td', async function () {
    console.log(event fired); });
```

Table `tr` are constructed dynamically.

Like above, I have to bind the same event for 10 tables.

**Option1**: Can I dynamically pass the `table id`

```
$('#' +tableNameString).on("dblclick", 'td', async function () {};
```

Is it possible?

**option 2**: `addEventListener()` ??

which option is optimal?

Share me some example on how to implement this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well yer it's possible

Comment: can you give the tables a common class?

Answer (score 2):

You could assign a class to all your tables in html, eg.

```
<table class="custTable">
</table>
```

And in your JS, add the event listener to that class, eg.

```
$('.custTable').on("dblclick", 'td', async function () { console.log(event fired); });
```

EDIT:

If your tables are created dynamically, inspect the table element to see if there is a specific class assigned to them to which you can bind the event listener.

Comment: or `$('body').on("dblclick", '.custTable td', ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding multiple selectors, separated by commas:

```
$("#elementOne, #elementTwo").on("dblclick", 'td', async function () {
  //do something
};
```